# Discord.py what is the code for announcement channels?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am creating a discord bot, I want to create a serverinfo command and I want one of the texts to show the amount of channels in the server.

The problem that I have is that I want announcement channels to be accounted for as well, but announcement channels are text channels, so that means that they are added onto the total for text channels. I also don't know what the code for announcement channels are, I have searched through the discord.py documents

I am using Python 3.9.5 and I believe that I am using the latest version of the discord module as when I went to install it again from the command prompt as it said "Requirement already satisfied: discord.py in c:\users\plant\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (1.7.2)"

I want something like this which is from the tatsu bot

[image]

my code for the channels

```
categories = ctx.guild.categories
text_channels = ctx.guild.text_channels
#announcements_channels = ctx.guild.announcements_channels
embed.add_field(name = f"Channels[{len(categories)+len(text_channels)}]",
                value = f"Category: {len(categories)}\nText: {len(text_channels)}\nNews: ",
                inline = False)
```

my code for serverinfo command

```
@client.command(name = "serverinfo", description = "Shows info about the current server.", aliases=["server"])
async def serverinfo(ctx): 
    embed = discord.Embed(title = f"{ctx.guild.name}", description = ".", colour = white)   
    roleCount = len(ctx.guild.roles)
    bots = [bot.mention for bot in ctx.guild.members if bot.bot]

    embed.set_thumbnail(url = str(ctx.guild.icon_url))
    
    embed.add_field(name = f"ID: **{ctx.guild.id}**", value = "⠀", inline = False)
    embed.add_field(name = "Verification Level", value = str(ctx.guild.verification_level).capitalize(), inline = False)
    embed.add_field(name = "Region", value =  str(ctx.guild.region).capitalize(), inline = False)
    categories = ctx.guild.categories
    text_channels = ctx.guild.text_channels
    #announcements_channels = ctx.guild.announcements_channels
    embed.add_field(name = f"Channels[{len(categories)+len(text_channels)}]",
                    value = f"Category: {len(categories)}\nText: {len(text_channels)}\nNews: ",
                    inline = False)
    embed.add_field(name = "Server Owner", value = str(ctx.guild.owner.mention), inline = False)
    embed.add_field(name = "Created On", value = ctx.guild.created_at.strftime("%a, %#d %B %Y, %I:%M %p UTC"), inline = False)
    embed.add_field(name = f"Roles[{len(ctx.guild.roles)}]", value = "⠀", inline = False)

    embed.set_footer(icon_url = str(ctx.author.avatar_url), text = f"Requested by {ctx.author.name}")

    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to go through each channel using a `for` loop, and see if it is a news channel. If it is, add it to a list. If not, that means it is a normal text channel and you can add it to your text channel list.

```
news_channels = 0
text_channels = 0
for channel in ctx.guild.text_channels:
  if channel.is_news():
    news_channels += 1
  else:
    text_channels += 1
```

Then you can do:

```
embed.add_field(name = "News channels", value = news_channels)
```

You can find this in the documentation [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=news#discord.TextChannel.is_news).

Comment: Thanks alot, your code is wrong just a little bit so I just had to do ctx.guild.text_channels instead of ctx.guild.channels.

Comment: @Atrixium ah sorry I missed that